# parent ViewController wont run willShowViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my first app and i am having trouble with the back button.
I need to run a custom method after the second viewController has disappeared and before the first viewController appears. I tried:

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
       willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{

  [self aMethod];

  }
```

but the aMethod is never executed.

is there something else i am missing?

thank you!

Comment: Add your method in `viewWillDisappear` in your second view controller.

Comment: the problem is i only need that method to run when the root view is going to be displayed because in the future it is going to have more viewControllers in the hierarchy. And if i go to viewController three viewWillDisapper will run too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify self as delegate of the navigation controller:

```
self.navigationController.delegate = self;
```